# Trying to parse SOAP response from webservice

Tags: android, soap

In my application I need to call a .NET webservice.

I was able to get response from server, it is:

```
anyType{
    nurses=anyType{
        nome=name1; 
        cognome=surname1; 
        urlFoto=url; 
        distanza=3.2; 
        disponibilita=true; 
        latitudine=45; 
        longitudine=9; 
    }; 
    nurses=anyType{
        nome=name2; 
        cognome=surname2; 
        urlFoto=url2; 
        distanza=4.1;
        disponibilita=true;
        latitudine=45.3; 
        longitudine=9.3; 
    };
}
```

How could I parse this response to have all data?

Comment: use [Ksoap2](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) library

Comment: I'm just using it for make a call to webservice but I can't understand how to parse the response above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using [KSOAP2 library](https://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/) *(as you said in comments above)* than you can do something like this:

```
SoapObject response = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();

for(int i=0; i<response.getPropertyCount(); i++){
    YourObjectModel obj = new YourObjectModel();
    SoapObject soapObj = (SoapObject) response.getProperty(i);

    obj.nome    = soapObj.getPrimitivePropertyAsString("nome");
    obj.cognome = soapObj.getPrimitivePropertyAsString("cognome");

    //Add to list
    nursesList.add(obj);
}
```

*However if you show the code where are you getting those data maybe we can be more specific in our answers*